# Multiple threads that start in order vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a method and I want to run multiple threads to complete it faster.

```
Public Sub createMaster()
    For intLoop = 0 To _MasterCount - 1 Step _Step
        _MasterCollection(intLoop) = New Champion(_MasterIDCollection(intLoop), _RRM.returnChampionInformation(_MasterIDCollection(intLoop).Substring(0, _MasterIDCollection(intLoop).Length() - 1), "na"))
    Next
End Sub
```

So, the method basically creates a collection for me. I've tried to do multiple threads to complete it faster, making a champion actually takes a second. Is there a way to make intLoop a specific variable? I tried making intloop = _Start where I increased _Start by one each time and it ended up making _Start all kinds of numbers. My main is like:

```
    Dim thread1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf createMaster)
    thread1.Start()
    Dim thread2 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf createMaster)
    thread2.Start()
    thread1.Join()
    thread2.Join()
```

I tried using a For loop with the thread and it didn't seem to work either. Does anyone know how to make this work in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your current code to use LINQ to map your `_MasterIDCollection` to `Champion` instances:

```
_MasterCollection = (
    From id In _MasterIDCollection
    Select New Champion(id, _RRM.returnChampionInformation(id.Substring(0, id.Length() - 1), "na"))
).ToList() ' or ToArray()?
```

LINQ is easily parallelizable by adding `AsParallel`, but you also need `AsOrdered` to maintain the order:

```
_MasterCollection = (
    From id In _MasterIDCollection.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
    Select New Champion(id, _RRM.returnChampionInformation(id.Substring(0, id.Length() - 1), "na"))
).ToList() ' or ToArray()?
```

By default, PLINQ will (I believe) run one thread per CPU core, but you can control that by adding `WithDegreeOfParallelism`.  Whether this is worthwhile depends on the type of work being done (e.g. I/O-bound or CPU-bound):

```
_MasterCollection = (
    From id In _MasterIDCollection.AsParallel().AsOrdered().WithDegreeOfParallelism(20)
    Select New Champion(id, _RRM.returnChampionInformation(id.Substring(0, id.Length() - 1), "na"))
).ToList() ' or ToArray()?
```

This requires .NET 4+, a reference to `System.Core` and `Using System.Linq`.  See the PLINQ [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, I had read about it on another website but your example helped me understand it much better.

Comment: I ran your answer, and it worked great. However, after like 4,000 new objects, the application starts to crawl and crashes. Any idea on the best way to handle it?

Comment: @RalphMaurmeier Without knowing what `_RRM.returnChampionInformation` and the `Champion` constructor are doing, I can only speculate.  Did you specify `WithDegreeOfParallelism`, and with what value?  Is there high CPU and/or memory usage when the app starts to crawl and crash?  What happens if you don't run it in parallel (i.e. the first example)?

Comment: This is for a different object. The new object sends a few requests to a server and then parses the response to create the object. Then, the information goes to some MySQL tables. I seem able to run it from my desktop without crashing, but when I run it on the server, it does eventually crash. The CPU stays at 99% while it runs. It pretty much soaks up anything it can. I currently broke it up into 100 objects and then it should just start over but still continue where it's at.

I have to scan games people play and pull the information from a server from Riot. They have a million games a day.

Comment: If it runs slower it does not crash. The speed isn't fast enough though. I may just need a bigger processor or I can run  it from multiple locations.